# return jquery object from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to return $ object from a function? Or do I need to wrap it up into a string?

```
function returnObj()
{
   obj = $("<img id='' src='' />");
   return obj;
}
var obj = returnObj();
alert(obj);  //returns [object Object]
```

Comment: `return` is a keyword. You shouldn't name a function it. It's probably causing syntax errors.

Comment: Stryner:i just gave some name here. thnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what you want after return object .. but this code May make sense

```
function returnObj()
{
   obj = $("<img id='imgID' src='' />");
   return obj;
}
var obj = returnObj();
alert(obj);
alert("This object id is: "+obj.attr('id'));  //returns [object Object].attr('id');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/c4c214ho/2/)

if you want to use that obj to append

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/c4c214ho/3/)

Comment: i need to return 'obj' and append it to some id.

Comment: @user3399326 just use $('#yourId').append(obj);

Answer (score 1):

Your object likely being returned correctly, it's just the behavior of the `alert` function that causes that output. When you alert on `obj`, the browser shows `[object Object]` because that is its default string representation of the object.

To see the full object, try `console.log(obj)` and then look in your browser's console output.

```js
function returnObj()
{
   obj = $("<img id='' src='' />");
   return obj;
}
var obj = returnObj();
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your browser console should look like this (I'm using the Chrome console, but any other browser would work too):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Maximilian i checked console and it doesn't print the whole $(...)

Comment: @user3399326 Looks fine to me. I edited my answer to give you an idea of what you're looking for. If I look at the prototype of the object, it is indeed a jQuery object.